# Is $x_n = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{m+ik-1}{n-1} \in [0,1]} |f(\frac{m+ik-1}{n-1})- f(\frac{m+(i-1)k-1}{n-1})|$ convergent when $f\in C\cap BV$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume $f$ is continuous and of bounded variation on the interval $[0,1]$, $f \in C[0,1] \cap BV[0,1]$. Then the sequence

$$
x_n = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{m+ik-1}{n-1} \in [0,1]} \left | f(\frac{m+ik-1}{n-1})- f(\frac{m+(i-1)k-1}{n-1})\right|
$$

with $m,k \in \mathbb{N}, m \leq k$ is bounded by the variation of $f$.

Can we show that the sequence is in fact convergent?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use uniform continuity for $f$ and estiamte the sum?

Comment: There are continuous functions which do not have bv on $[0,1]$ so even boundness may not hold; maybe if $f$ is $C^1$ using mean value something can be done

Comment: what are $n,m,k?\,\,$

Comment: I forgot to write down that $f$ is of bounded variation. We then have a bounded sequence.

Comment: What is the point of $m\le k?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem: If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1],$ then

$$\lim_{|P|\to 0} \sum_{P}|\Delta f| = V_0^1(f).$$

Here $P$ is a partition of $[0,1],$ $|P|$ denotes the mesh size of $P,$ and $V_0^1(f)$ is the total variation of $f$ on $[0,1]$ (which might be $\infty$). I hope the notation $\sum_{P}|\Delta f|$ explains itself.

The theorem implies the following solution to your question: With your hypotheses, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = V_0^1(f).$ To see this, fix $m,k$ and define the partitions

$$P_n = \left (\{\frac{m+ik-1}{n-1} : i\in \mathbb N\}\cap [0,1]\right) \cup \{0,1\}.$$

Check that $|P_n|$ is on the order of $1/n$ as $n\to \infty.$ Thus by the theorem,

$$\tag 1 \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{P_n}|\Delta f| = V_0^1(f).$$

Now the sums in $(1)$ could be slightly larger than the sums in your problem, due to the fact that $0,1$ may not be among the sampling points that you specify. That's no problem. The most we could be adding is

$$\tag 2|f((a_n)-f(0)| + |f(1)-f(b_n)|,$$

where $a_n$ is the first of your points, and $b_n$ is the last of your points. Because $|a_n-0|,|1-b_n|=O(1/n),$ the continuity of $f$ shows the contribution in $(2)$ disappears in the limit. This proves $x_n \to V_0^1$ as desired.

Have you previously encountered the theorem I used?

---

**Added later:** Proof of the Thm: I'll prove it for the case $V_0^1(f)<\infty.$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there is a partition $P=\{0=x_0<x_1<\cdots <x_n=1\}$ such that

$$\sum_{P}|\Delta f| > V_0^1(f)-\epsilon.$$

Let $I_k=(x_{k-1},x_k).$ If $\delta>0$ is small enough, then i) any partition $Q$ with $|Q|<\delta$ will contain at least two points in every $I_k,$ and ii) $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| <\epsilon/(2n).$ Property ii) follows from the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[0,1].$

Fix such a $\delta,$ and assume $|Q|<\delta. $ I'll show $\sum_{Q}|\Delta f|>V_0^1(f)-2\epsilon.$ That will prove the theorem.

For $k=1,\dots,n,$ define $Q_k= Q\cap I_k.$ Since each $Q_k$ has at least two points, we can define $a_k= \min Q_k,$ $b_k = \max Q_k.$ Let $R$ be the partition $R=P\cup (Q_1 \cup \cdots \cup Q_n).$ Because $R$ is a refinement of $P,$ we have

$$\sum_{R}|\Delta f| \ge \sum_{P}|\Delta f| > V_0^1(f)-\epsilon.$$

Write

$$\sum_{R}|\Delta f| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{Q_k}|\Delta f| + \sum_{k=1}^{n}(|f(a_k)-f(x_{k-1})| + |f(x_k)-b_k|).$$

Each summand in the second sum on the right is $<2\epsilon/(2n)$ by ii) above, hence that sum $<\epsilon.$ It follows that the first sum on the right is at least $\sum_{R}|\Delta f|-\epsilon.$ Since $\sum_{Q}|\Delta f|\ge  \sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{Q_k}|\Delta f|,$ we're done.

Comment: Oh that's a nice theorem. I didn't see this before. Can you provide me some literature where I can find this statement with a proof?

Comment: Actually I haven't see the result anywhere before myself, and I can't find it on the web. I'll write up a proof soon.

Comment: @AugustoS.  I had proved the theorem, just hadn't posted a proof. I thought maybe the OP might know the result, or that it could be found online, so I put my participation on hold. I was surprised that I couldn't find a proof online. Now I've posted a proof. As for your answer, it seemed complicated to me (axiom of choice?). I didn't read it carefully. So I had no idea what your Corollary 2 implied, or even if it was true. I thought I could post an answer that was less complicated and more elementary, one that involved a different approach, and that's the route I took.