# Question of total variation of functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I have the following question:

> > Is it true that $V(f)=\lim_{||P||\rightarrow0}V_P(f)$?

To make clear what I mean: Let $f:[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $P=\{
t_0=a<\cdots<t_m=b
\}
$ a partition of $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$, then 
$
V_P(f)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}| f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1}) |.
$

Then $V(f)=$sup$
\{
V_P(f):P\mbox{ is a partition of } [a,b]
\}$

Now, if f is not of bounded variation, I know this to be false.
For example, take $f=\begin{cases}
0 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
1 & x\in\mathbb{R-Q}
\end{cases}$

Then I can find succesions $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$,$(Q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ so that 
$V_{P_n}(f)\rightarrow 0$, $V_{Q_n}(f)\rightarrow \infty$. Showing that in particular, $\lim_{||P||\rightarrow0}V_P(f)$ does not exists(not even $\pm\infty$)

However, I feel like this is cheating. Because $f$ is not of bounded variation.(Thomae's function fails in the same manner) So:

> > Is it possible to find a counterexample to the question where f is of bounded variation? If not, how does one prove it?

PS: I hope I made myself clear, any help is appreciated and very welcome. Feel free to edit anything to might think will help to make the question clearer. Thanks everyone

Comment: Please note the definition of the limit is not strictly the usual, but can we easily thought to be: $\forall \epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ if $||P||<\delta$ then $L-V_P(f)<\epsilon$ (where $L = \lim_{||P||\rightarrow0}V_P(f)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as a counterexample the function $f:[-1,1] \to \Bbb{R}$ such that 
                                                                     $f(x)=\begin{cases}\
                                                                         0 & x \neq 0\\
                                                                         1 & x=0\\
                                                                        \end{cases}$

> The limiting property  is valid if $f$ is  continuous  and has bounded variation on the interval $[a,b]$

Comment: Oh, true! I feel kind of stupid now, but you're right

Comment: Take a sequence  of partitions $P_n$ that their norm $||.|| $ goes to zero and and $0$ is not a partition point of any of the partitions $P_n$

Comment: Do not worry..glad i helped.

Comment: And do you know how to prove the case where f is continous?

Comment: There is a proof i believe in the book: Measure and Integral of  Zygmund-Wheeden

Comment: Yeah, I was able to find it. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: There is also a proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149258/is-x-n-sum-i-in-mathbbn-fracmik-1n-1-in-0-1-f-fracmik-1/3155818#3155818